# notepad-plus-plus snap does not start on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, snapcraft

I installed notepad-plus-plus on Ubuntu machine. It was working fine. With no evident reason it stopped to work. Icon disappeared from application list. When I launch shell script `/snap/notepad-plus-plus/current/bin/notepad-plus-plus` I got error message:

> You need to connect this snap to the wine-platform-i386 snap.
>
> snap connect :wine-platform-plug wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable

I removed snapd (`sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`) and install it again. Same behavior.
I installed notepad-plus-plus snap on another Ubuntu system and it works fine.

How to 'connect' notepad-plus-plus snap to the wine-platform-i386 snap?

Comment: Question was voted as "Question does not show any research effort, not clear or not useful"
-I spent half of day trying to get notepad-plus-plus working on Ubuntu. No success.
-If not clear, please ask to clarify
-Not useful? It would be very useful to me to get notepad-plus-plus working.
Google search does not give any hint. Snap web site is of no use. If someone downwoted s/he should offer solution ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing same problem and I used these commands. Hopefully its working fine now.

1.`sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus`
2.`sudo snap connect notepad-plus-plus:process-control`
3.`snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by these commamds in Linux.
1.snap install wine-platform-5-stable
2.snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-5-stable wine-platform-5-stable
3.snap run notepad-plus-plus

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issued by these command:

1. snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-6-stable
2. snap install wine-platform-6-stable
3. snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-6-stable wine-platform-6-stable

And then check it again by notepad-plus-plus

Phoungvd.

Answer (score 0):

try this on command line :

> snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug snap install
>
> wine-platform snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug
>
> wine-platform:wine-base-stable

then try opening notepad

> notepad-plus-plus